# Use "Redirect" and "ProxyPass"

Tags: apache, proxypass

I would like to force my users to use https to log in.
Unfortunately the "redirect" directive does not seem to work in cunjunction with "ProxyPass"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain.com
  # This does not work
  Redirect permanent /app/login.jsp https://www.domain.com/app/login.jsp
  ProxyPass         /app    http://localhost:8080/app
  ProxyPassReverse  /app    http://localhost:8080/app
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: `Redirect permanent /app/login.jsp https://www.domain.com/app/login.jsp` should redirect to https version, but you are showing only config for the http version (port 80)

Comment: Thanks Cheery but it actually does not work (not redirected to the https version). I didn't show the https config because it work (i can manually request `https://www.domain.com/app/login.jsp`)

Comment: Redirect Directive is not related to ProxyPass and should work if matched without caring about the further directives. The problem is somewhere else, not here. For testing purposes remove `permanent` as browser caches 301 responses.

Comment: I removed `permanent`but it still does not work. But if I add `Redirect /foo https://www.domain.com/app/login.jsp` it gets redirected : doesn't it mean that that the `ProxyPass` preceeds the `Redirect` directive ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. You can try to use mod_rewrite instead of redirect - I think it has higher priority. Or, try to use Location for ProxyPass..

Comment: I tried with mod_rewrite : still no redirection (`RewriteRule ^/app/login.jsp$ https://www.domain.com/app/login.jsp [R=301,L]`)

Answer (score 13):

Found an answer to this question here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/605931/can-you-use-redirect-and-proxypass-at-the-same-time

The following needs to be added before the other proxypass directives:

ProxyPass /app/login.jsp !

Answer (score 7):

I had a more complicated use case and it required the use of `ProxyPassMatch`. It went a little something like this:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/app(/(index.html)?)?$ !
RedirectMatch ^/app(/(index.html)?)?$ /path/to/login/page.html

ProxyPass /app/* http://remote-server/app
ProxyPassReverse /app/* http://remote-server/app
```

I had to use `ProxyPassMatch` because `ProxyPass` otherwise performs prefix-matching. You need to match on the end-of-string, so `ProxyPassMatch` with a `$` regular expression metacharacter is critical.

Here, `RedirectMatch` is used in the same way, because `Redirect` also performs prefix-matching as well. The two directives also have a nice symmetry, too.

Answer (score 0):

As you identified, the fact you have a `ProxyPass` for location `/app` means anything hitting that path will be subject to the proxy.

You could omit using `ProxyPass` and do the proxy with a `RewriteRule` and the proxy `[P]` flag:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain.com

  RewriteRule ^/(app/login.jsp)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^/app(.*) http://localhost:8080/app$1 [P]

  ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8080/app

</VirtualHost>
```